# Port Mingw32 based code to msvc2008

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, cross-platform, mingw

We recently had a new requirement to use the phonon component of Qt, which on windows requires Visual Studio.

I installed VS2008 and ran a compile.  There are a stack of problems due to make not working anything like nmake.

Since I need to maintain cross-platform I want to test which compiler is being used so that I can make changes as required.

An example is that the **PRETTY_FUNCTION** is a g++ macro with **FUNCDNAME**  being the VC equivalent. How do I test which compiler I am using to determine which macro to call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [_MSC_VER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) macro. If it is defined, you're using Visual Studio:

```
 #ifdef _MSC_VER
 ... MSVC code ...
 #else
 ... other compiler ...
 #endif
```